# Add fragment to CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

It seems like you can't add a fragment to a CoordinatorLayout. When I attempt to insert one, nothing crashes but the fragment just doesn't show up, but when I evaluate its dimensions they are non-zero. If I change the `CoordinatorLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` the fragment shows up. If I add an `EditText` to the `CoordinatorLayout` the `EditText` will show up. Why is the fragment not showing up in the `CoordinatorLayout`?

My XML is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView      
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.mypackage.Behavior">

    </FrameLayout> 
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am replacing the `FrameLayout` with my fragment as follows:

```
getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, MyFragment.TAG)
                    .commit();
```

Comment: can you show the behavior?

Comment: @GPack It's empty right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was actually with the fragment view I was adding. It had margins that pushed it off screen. The method in the question works.